# How to create a new laravel project without internet connectivity?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3

I have composer installed and can use the

```
laravel new ProjectName
```

command to create a new project. However this requires an active internet connection. I need to be able to do the same thing offline as well. Will it work if I just copy the files from one project and then paste them in another folder with the required name?

For example. if I already have a project called 'blog' and I just created a new directory 'blog1' and pasted all the files in "blog" folder there, would that give me a new project blog1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it a number of times specially on my staging server where i normally duplicate a laravel application and then configure it and put my new code through ftp. it works fine. u have configure the things.